# Dumping current .zshrc from terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, arch-linux, zsh

I've wanted to make quick edit in a .zshrc, but vim said that it can't be written or something. So I quit, with :q!. Then I wanted to reopen this file... and it was empty.

I still have terminal open which works with previous configuration. How can I restore complete .zshrc(or as close to complete) from it? I've already saved my aliases with 'alias' command.

Comment: You should look around at your disk partitions. Some may  be full.

Comment: Yes, that was likely a source of the problem. My root partition was full, I wanted to clean it up, found some tool, installed it, then I wanted to add alias for conveniance of using it to .zshrc.... and then it disappeared. Now I have cleaned up 25% of root partition, but there is no .zshrc... I wonder how it happened. Because partition being full should maybe cause impossibility of editing this file... but *deleting* it?

Comment: _it can't be written **or something**_  I don't think that vi complained by saying literally _or something_. Please paste next time the exact eror message. If you have accidentally deleted your file, you have to create it from your backup. You do make regular backups, don't you?

Answer (score 13):

First of, there is no way to get the actual `~/.zshrc` from a running shell session. This is mainly due to the fact that `~/.zshrc` is essentially a shell script and only the settings it does make it into the shell session, but not the logic behind the settings.

Nevertheless, you actually can get some information from a running shell session, that may help you in recreating some of the settings that were in your lost .zshrc:

- As you already noted, you can get your aliases from the shell builtin `alias`. With `alias -L` you actually can get a list of calls to `alias`, which you can put into your new `~/.zshrc` just as-is.
- Calling `setopt` gives you a list of the shell options that are not set to the default values.
- `set` will print a list of all parameters and their values. A lot of it was probably *not* set explicitly in your configuration, but some of it was. Settings like the prompts (`PROMPT`, `PROMPT2`, `PROMPT3`, `PROMPT4`, `RPROMPT` and `RPROMPT2`), history (`HISTSIZE`, `SAVEHIST`, `HISTFILE`, etc.), default editor (`EDITOR`) and pager (`PAGER`) can be found there, so having a look may be worth it.
- `autoload` will give at least some indication what modules were loaded. You can ignore any function declaration starting with an underscore as they are most likely loaded by the completion system. Although the rest may not necessarily have been loaded explicitly, it will at least give some indication.
- `zstyle -L` will print a list of the settings made with `zstyle` as list of commands (just like `alias -L`).
- `bindkey -L` will print your current keymap as a list of commands. If the list is pretty long and does not have (a lot of) commands starting with `vi-` your shell probably ran in emacs mode, in which case putting `bindkey -e` into your new `zshrc` will probably restore most settings. For the rest you can diff the outputs of `bindkey -L` in the running and a new shell. If you utilized the `vicmd` mode those settings can be retrieved with `bindkey -aL`.
- `functions` gives you the listings of the functions defined in your session. Again, not all of them may have been actually set in your configuration, but it is a starting point.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting to this pretty late, but having previously been in need of this information myself, I can say that you deserve a damn sight more upvotes than it looks like you currently have.  You're doing God's work, sir.  :)

Comment: I totally agree with you @JonCarter. I've lost my `.zshrc` and this answer has helped me to restore the majority of the file. Congratulations @Adaephon

Answer (score 0):

Another useful command is `typeset` to retrieve all declared variables from the current session, so you can find for example the list of plugins you had installed: `typeset | grep plugins=`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
history | grep ".zshrc"
```

Look for the commands or output related to your .zshrc file. The contents of the file might have been displayed in your terminal at some point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).